# IIS 7- Can I combine EV SSL with Wild card certificates?

Tags: ssl, iis-7

Our site has a lot sub-domains which we all secure with a wildcard SSL certificate. Now we want to add an EV-SSL certificate for our *www* sub-domain to increase security and trust in our site. The other sub-domains still have to use the wildcard certificate.

The site is configured as a single site on IIS 7 with all sub-domains listed as http(s) bindings.

Is it possible in IIS 7 to use these two certificate types on one domain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to have two different certificates for the same domain name with the help of SNI technology and need to binding your certificates during configuration.

You need to request EV SSL certificate for your example.com which will secure both versions of the domain as www and non-www.

For subdomains security, you can apply for Wildcard SSL certificate for *.example.com

References –

https://www.ssl2buy.com/wiki/server-name-indication-sni-use-multiple-ssl-on-a-single-ip

https://support.comodo.com/index.php?/Knowledgebase/Article/View/639/0/certificate-installation-microsoft-iis-7x

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible that you can use two SSL certificate type for same domain name. Because SSL certificate is issued to FQDN (Fully Qualified domain name).

So you can't use two SSL certificate for same domain name.

**For example,**

If you are using wildcard ssl certificate for blog.xyz.com then you can't take EV SSL certificate for that same domain name.